# vlookup with blank look up value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, vlookup

I have a Vlookup formula that I want to return `0` if the returned value is empty.

example:
`=(VLOOKUP(A6,F:G,2,0)+1)*C6`

```
+-------+--------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+
|       |        |       |           | Name  | Value |
+-------+--------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Name  | lookup | Price | New price | Bread | 1%    |
| Bread |        | 1     | 1.01      | Milk  | 2%    |
|       | #N/A   | 2     | #N/A      | Water | 3%    |
| Water | 0.03   | 0.1   | 0.103     |       |       |
+-------+--------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

how would I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Throw an [iferror](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/iferror-function-HA001231765.aspx) into it

`=IFERROR((VLOOKUP(A6,F:G,2,0)+1)*C6, 0)`

Comment: @jon if this answer solves your question, please hit the green checkmark to the left of the answer to mark the question as answered. This will allow users looking for a similar solution to see that this worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly want to do that when A6 is blank only then you can use this version

`=IF(A6="",0,(VLOOKUP(A6,F:G,2,0)+1)*C6)`

Raystafarian's suggestion will also deal with situations where A6 is not blank but does not exist in column F